# How do I write a java program so that it outputs the following line: (String)

Tags: java, string

a ' and a "? Or between a " and a \"?

// I am having trouble getting the program to output the \" .

Comment: Post the code you're having problems with and describe the problem specifically.

Comment: [Escape sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you'll need to escape the `\`. Something like,

```
System.out.println("a ' and a \"? Or between a \" and a \\\"?");
```

which outputs (as requested)

```
a ' and a "? Or between a " and a \"?
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't adding three \\\ in front of it, just two and it wasn't working!

Comment: Actually there's no 3 \ : there are 2 \ first, which is an escaped \, followed by \", which is an escaped ".

Answer (score 0):

You can output a backslash by escaping it :

```
System.out.println("\\");
```